# compile-time errors in third-parties (guaranteed to be valid) code

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm using `QuickFAST` in my project. When I try to compile I receive a lot of compile-time errors in `QuickFAST`. But `QuickFAST` code is guaranteed to be valid (and when I open it separately I able to compile it).

Why do I receive this compile-time error in valid code and how to fix it?

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ValueMessageBuilder> ValueMessageBuilderPtr;

Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\messages\ValueMessageBuilder_fwd.h 14  1   FastNativeAdapter

typedef boost::uint16_t uint16;

Error   15  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   E:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\Common\Types.h 23  1   FastNativeAdapter

typedef boost::shared_ptr<ValueMessageBuilder> ValueMessageBuilderPtr;

Error   1   error C2653: 'boost' : is not a class or namespace name e:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\messages\ValueMessageBuilder_fwd.h 14  1   FastNativeAdapter


void setValue(const uint64 value)

Error   255 error C2535: 'void QuickFAST::Value::setValue(const int)' : member function already defined or declared E:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\Common\Value.h 99  1   FastNativeAdapter


virtual void addValue(FieldIdentityCPtr & identity, ValueType::Type type, const uint64 value) = 0;

Error   45  error C2535: 'void QuickFAST::Messages::ValueMessageBuilder::addValue(QuickFAST::Messages::FieldIdentityCPtr &,QuickFAST::ValueType::Type,const int)' : member function already defined or declared E:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\Messages\ValueMessageBuilder.h 42  1   FastNativeAdapter

void setValue(const int8 value)
{
  class_ = SIGNEDINTEGER;
  cachedString_ = false;
  signedInteger_ = value;
}

Error   310 error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier    E:\quickfast\quickfast_1_4_0\src\Common\Value.h 147 1   FastNativeAdapter
```

`boost` include and lib files are added to the project.

**upd:**

I've found that it's enough to just include `QuickFAST` file, like that `#include "Messages/ValueMessageBuilder.h"`. After that I receive compile errors above despite of the fact that I never instatiate or use any `QuickFAST` classes.

If I remove`#include "Messages/ValueMessageBuilder.h"` than errors disappear (because in entire program I never refer to any `QuickFAST` files.

So the point is - it's enough to just include the file. So probaly somehow `QuickFAST` sources are linked wrong to my project? I've just added include and lib files in project properties...

Comment: Are you sure, you have `#incldue <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` and the paths are correctly added?

Comment: i do not use shared_ptr. if library use it it must include it itself? regarding boost i think yes paths are correctly added as i'm using some boost methods and they do work. and some compile-time errors are not about boost so I guess this problem is not boost-related

Comment: Those errors are sometimes tedious to track down, but not hard: **1** take the source file where you get the errors into a new project, including include paths etc, so you get the error there. **2** delete every line in the source that does not contribute to the error, remove includes that don't contribute to the error. Recompile often to check that the error still appears and does not change. **3** subsequently copy the content of included headers and replace the corresponding include directives, i.e. play preprocessor. **4** goto 2. That way you get the essence of the error

Comment: @ArneMertz if I open same source file in another project i DO NOT get errors. because files are valid. i get errors in my project only.

Comment: @ArneMertz: No, this is a case of bug in one header taking effect in another. Moving the code in new project won't help (the code is correct). Reordering of the headers will.

Comment: If the error disappears in another project, there has to be something different. Other headers get included, other `#define`s lead to different code to be compiled or something else. You could as well do the same steps in the project where you get the errors and roll back the changes later (of course you use version control, do you?)

Comment: @ArneMertz of course i do use version control. i tried to use "header" and "lib" files from the project that compile in project that does not compile but that doesn't help. I'm not sure what else can be done. there should be straightforward way to understand why i receive such a strange error as `error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier` for example...

Comment: @ArneMertz: It is obvious from the onset that the errors are provoked by some other header. Looking at version control is unlikely to be of help, because the version that does not compile was probably never committed. It's the change that introduces the #include that does not compile.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Reading your instructions carefully again they are correct, but the first one is confusing. There is no point in creating new project here; in the actual project that fails, start commenting out things...

Comment: Ok if the current version is not checked in, just save that source somewhere. If the changes that lead to the error are not too big, e.g. just a new included header, then start with replacing that include ba the headers content, erasing as much of it as possible without losing the error - then you'll find what part of that header is making trouble. Some advice to include order: include standard headers first, boost after that, other libs after those, and your own last. That way errors in your headers won't crop up in stable library headers.

Comment: i've added **upd** to description

Answer (score 0):

Found that in [FAQ of QuickFAST](https://code.google.com/p/quickfast/wiki/FAQ#I%27m_having_trouble_building_my_application_when_I_include_Q) and it helped:

To resolve this most applications should set `$QUICKFAST_HOME/src` as an include directory *and include `<Application/QuickFAST.h>` before including any other QuickFAST headers.* Applications that use precompiled headers should include this header in their precompiled header file.

Just need to include `Application/QuickFAST.h` before any other includes.

Comment: Seems you are right. I'd call that an extremely bad design. The headers should either include their dependencies (it incurs no penalty when those dependencies were already included) or at least have a check for the dependency guard and give an explicit error saying what must be included before them. But it's what you have to live with.